# How do i find product name even if user enter wrong spelling in monogdb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

i  am creating a search bar , i want to find the user even if the spelling is entered wrong by the user , i know $regex could be used for this purpose but couldn't do it .  i have  so far found how to implement case insensitive query for finding product .

```
if(typeof req.body.search!='undefined' && req.body.search!=''){

productSchema.find({productname:{$regex:req.body.search,$options:"i"}}).then((prd,err) => {

if (prd) {
    console.log(prd)
}


})
```

Comment: Give an example of a misspelled query and what you want it to match.

Comment: @codemonkey  let say the user search for laptops but he misspell it as lptop.  even then i want to search accuratly .thanks.

Comment: Hi, I think text index is what you are looking for. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/